# How to forward RTP stream with GStreamer?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

In my LAN, I have an IP camera and two PC. I am able to record and play streaming data from each PC.

For example, to record the streaming data:

```
gst-launch-0.10 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.100.50/live.sdp latency=0 ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! avimux ! filesink location=sample.avi
```

To play:

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin uri=rtsp://192.168.100.50/live.sdp
```

Now, I want PC1 receives and forwards the streaming data upon demand from PC2.

Is this possible with GStreamer? If it is, what are the commands needed by PC1 and PC2?

Answer (score 2):

One can directly forward without decoding and encoding .. thus saving processing

rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.160:60661/test  latency=0 ! rtph264depay !  rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96

Comment: I get the following error when i try this.
-------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2: Internal data flow error.


Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)

Execution ended

Answer (score -2):

Well, question resolved.

Pipeline at PC1:

```
gst-launch-0.10 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.100.50/live.sdp latency=0 ! decodebin ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! udpsink host=192.168.100.95 port=51234
```

IP address of PC2: 192.168.100.95

Pipeline at PC2:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=51234 ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```